# How can I find out which files have been opened by the application?

Tags: php, twig

`get_included_files()` is useful but it's not including files opened using fopen or `file_get_contents`.

I have also tried using `strace` but I can't seem to home in the specific PHP process.

More specifically, I'm using `twig` for templating and I'd like to know which files have been included in what order.

I have so far tried to use strace like this but am getting permission errors attaching to the process.

```
<?php

$pid = getmypid();

echo `strace -p {$pid} 2>&1 > log &`;

file_put_contents( 'afile', 'foobar' );
```

The output...

> strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): Operation not permitted
>   Could not attach to process. If your uid matches the uid of the target
>   process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or
>   try again as the root user. For more details, see
>   /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf

Comment: I would suppose twig can give you this information.

Comment: Maybe, I'm looking at that angle now, but even so I think it would be useful in a broader context.

Comment: That would add potentionaly large overhead. You can still use xdebug's function traces feature.

Comment: Hi Marek, what would add the overhead? Are you thinking of anything specifically?

Comment: To remember all files that were opened during script execution.

Comment: I'm not worried about the overhead. I've expanded on the question to include what I've been trying to get work.#

Answer (score 0):

You can use a classic workaround:

Wrap all file opening functions, eg: `my_fopen`, and do the logging there.

Just a couple of lines of code + a search&replace on the codebase.

Comment: thanks, it's a good tip, but the code base is very large and includes lots of third party vendor code.